# Set private field within constructor using set validation from property

Tags: c#, constructor, properties

So.. How do i validate a private instance variable (field) with a property inside of a constructor?

I have this code that works, but I have a strong feeling this is not how it is supposed to be done:

```
class Account
    {
        private decimal acctBalance = 0;

        public decimal AcctBalance
        {
            get
            {
                return acctBalance;
            }
            set
            {
                if (acctBalance >= 0)
                    acctBalance = value;
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid balance, balance set to 0");
                    acctBalance = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        public Account(decimal balance)
        {
            acctBalance = balance;
            AcctBalance = acctBalance;
        }
    }
```

I just want to make sure that this is the correct way to do it

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is mostly right, although there are a couple of issues. I fixed them and annotated the code with comments where I did.

```
class Account
{
    private decimal acctBalance = 0;

    public decimal AcctBalance
    {
        get
        {
            return acctBalance;
        }
        set
        {
            //modified to check value instead of acctBalance
            if (value >= 0)
                acctBalance = value;
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid balance, balance set to 0");
                acctBalance = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public Account(decimal balance)
    {
        //redundant! Changing AcctBalance changes acctBalance
        //acctBalance = balance;
        AcctBalance = balance; 
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a homework assignment that specifically asks me to use a public property to set the private field, I just want to make sure this is the correct way to do it, or at least the commonly accepted way

Comment: Here are the exact instructions: "Base class Account should include one private instance variable of type decimal to represent the account balance. The class should provide a constructor that receives an initial balance and uses it to initialize the instance variable with a public property. The property should validate the initial balance to ensure that it is greater than or equal to 0.0. If not, the balance should be set to 0.0, and the set accessor should display an error message, indicating that the initial balance was invalid."

Comment: +1 for fixing the setter (`value` vs private field name - as originally written it wouldn't have done what the OP expected) and the redundancy in the constructor :)

Comment: Ahh!!! It all makes sense now!! I never would have thought of it working that way, I knew there was a better way! Thank you so much :)